# Swift Auto Documentation jazzy for pod folder only

Tags: ios, swift, documentation-generation, jazzy

I am writing an SKD in Swift and I have an example project as a target.  The target is there for testing the network calls that the SDK makes.

My project structure looks something like this

```
-project
  ->sampleViewController
  ->storyboard
  ->plist
-pods
  ->core
    ->development
      -> Main
        -> Network
        -> Objects
        -> Protocols
        -> Structs
  -> RxSwift
  -> Fakery
  -> tw10
```

All of the files in folders that are subfolders of 'development' all are commented swift files and when option clicked show the notes I am hoping to export

I have downloaded jazzy and I cannot see a way to specify a path extension more over it appears to build the project and take out the comments of the target.

However I don't want this as all the code in my target is not what I am going to be shipping when I am done.

My question is, Is there a way to pass a folder extension e.g. ("/mac/project/target/development") to jazzy (or any other gem or program) so that I can auto generate the documentation for my code? Or does anyone know of a better solution or library I could use before I type it all out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run jazzy -h and you can see

```
    --source-directory DIRPATH   The directory that contains the source to be documented
-e, --exclude file1,file2,…fileN Files to be excluded from documentation
```

Just play around :).

Answer (score 1):

Just write:

```
jazzy --podspec PathOfYourPodspec
```

...and your documentation folder will be created.